# Saving an entity graph using entity framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-6

I am writing a Data Access Layer using Entity Framework 6. What I want is that when I invoke the `SaveChanges()` method on the `DbContext`, it will save the entity together with the set of relevant entities associated via navigation properties. Following is the simple code I am trying to do.

```
public class Customer
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual IEnumerable<PhoneNumber> { get; set; }
}

public class PhoneNumber
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
}    

public class SampleContext : DbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<PhoneNumber> PhoneNumbers { get; set; }
}

using(var context = new SampleContext())
{
     var customer = new Customer { ID = 1, Name = "John" };
     customer.PhoneNumbers = new PhoneNumbers[]
     {
          new PhoneNumber { ID = 1, Number = "1.111.1111111" },
          new PhoneNumber { ID = 2, Number = "1.111.1111112" }
     }
     context.Customers.Add(customer);
     context.SaveChanges();
}
```

The above code saves the customer in the customers table but saves nothing in the PhoneNumbers table.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20098287/save-detached-object-graph-using-entity-framework-code-first-causes-primary-key

Comment: @Yanshof, The blog is something different, the concept of Navigation properties has totally been messed up in that blog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strange but found a solution. The above code need a little modification to make it work. Followings are the modifications:

```
 // In Customer class, changed following line:
 public virtual IEnumerable<PhoneNumber> { get; set; }

 // To:
 public virtual ICollection<PhoneNumber> { get; set; }

 // Then in using block initialized entities as follows:
 using(var context = new SampleContext())
 {
      var customer = new Customer { ID = 1, Name = "John", PhoneNumbers = new List<PhoneNumber>() };
      customer.PhoneNumbers.Add(new PhoneNumber { ID = 1, Number = "1.111.1111111" });
      context.Customers.Add(customer);
      context.SaveChanges();
 }
```